# How to run code in VSCode using the terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really confused on why this isn't working.  I assign the value 5 to the variables num_one and then assign the value 10 to num_two.  Then I add them together and print that but it outputs 9 to the terminal.

The name of the file is variables.py and when I try to run it VSCode using "py variables.py", "python variables.py", or "python3 variables.py" it outputs 9 to the terminal.  Obviously, I'm expecting the answer to be 15 but for some reason it's not updating.

```
num_one = 5
num_two = 10
print(num_one + num_two)
```

Comment: So many things could be going on here, but clearly you're not running *this* code. In your terminal, if you type `cat variables.py`, does it display this file? Are you in the right directory? Is the file saved to disk, with this contents?

Comment: remember to save the file to update, if you dont save vscode runs the latest save file, it is possible your variables were different before and the edit does not reflect

Answer (score 0):

That code produces the expected `15`.

```
>>> num_one = 5
>>> num_two = 10
>>> print(num_one + num_two)
15
>>>
```

You didn't supply any config or debug details
that would help us understand how your IDE
interpreter differs from the cPython 3.10.8
which produced the above results.